# Terminate pool processes python 2.7

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing, threadpool

My goal is pretty simple:

Terminate all processes in the pool after n seconds.

```
p = Pool(5)
def f(x):
  return x*x

p.map(f, [1,2,3])
```

I need to use Pool and not multiprocessing.Process

Is there a way to terminate the whole pool or all the processes in it?

Pool of threads is also an option.

Comment: Are you talking about a pool of processes or a pool of threads? Your question talks about processes but you have tagged this as threadpool.

Comment: @Hannu threads is also an option. I updated the question. Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at [`Pool.close()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.close) and [`Pool.terminate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.terminate) (`terminate()` should be a last resort).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with threads (no way to force a thread to exit from the outside). You can `terminate()` a process pool.

Something like this, but you need to use map_async. If you use the blocking map, then you are probably out of luck.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import sleep

def worker(x):
    print(x)
    sleep(50)

tasks = [x for x in range(0,10)]

p = Pool()

q = p.map_async(worker, tasks)
q.wait(10)
try:
    p.terminate()
    p.join()
except:
    pass
print("done")
```

This submits tasks to a pool and after 10 seconds terminates the pool if it has not completed yet. This may or may not be suitable for your purposes.